# How to create an (over)spray effect (in gimp)?

Tags: gimp

**How to create an overspray effect?**

I tried fading out the selection and fill it with one color on a background layer and tried different brushes and tools, but without luck. It's mainly to geht the spray painted look at all.

Thanks.

**Before:**

[image: no overspray]

**After:**

[image: overspray]

*Edit to clean up the question*

Comment: Why not simply use a scatter like brush to paint with red over the edges or apply it to a path along the edge or another x ways :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can ask GIMP questions here. Here's a super easy method.

1. Fill a circle with red, on its own layer
2. *Select > None*
3. Duplicate the layer
4. Apply some Gaussian blur to the top layer
5. Set the layer mode to "Dissolve"

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another method:

1. Make a circle selection
2. Bucket-fill with color
3. `Select>Invert`
4. `Filter>Noise>Spread...` and give the maximum extent of the "spill"

[image]

You can also use `Select>Feather` to blur the selection a bit to avoid the sharp edge:

[image]